# Control video after casting from Android app in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, chromecast, google-cast

I am using google chromeCast for casting the video. I have successfully cast a video from my app to TV but not able to find any solution for controlling that video like play pause and move forward. Is this possible with Xamarin?

Comment: If it is possible with Android native, it is possible with Xamarin.Android. When playing the video on the Android device, do you have the playback controls? If so, you should still be able to use them to control the cast video.

Comment: Hi @Mannu how did you do to cast the video?
Please share with us how to achive the cast